# Read file and Iterate over a list of strings using Scala for loop

Tags: scala, for-loop

How can you build a `Seq` of `Strings` read from a file using a for loop in scala?

So I have a file `bla.txt`:

`1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9`

```
val lines = Source.fromResource("bla.txt").getLines
val result = (for {
  line <- lines
  l = line.split(" ")      
} yield {
    new String(l(0) + l(1) + l(2))
}).toSeq
```

Printing `result` gives me: events: `Stream(123, ?)` - Why does it not process the second and third lines of the file?

Comment: why don't you use fromFile api and map functions? that would be easy I guess.

Comment: Actually `toSeq` here is providing you with a `Stream` which you can think of as `Lazy List`. If you want to you can use `toList` instead of `toSeq` to get  the whole `List`

Comment: `toList` fixed my issue - thanks!

Comment: Can you close the question in that case?